# Countdown timer not working within setTimeout(function() { ... }

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

Function totsessie2stopt(); will run ok here: https://jsfiddle.net/szua2fed/

```
    // Begin countdown
function totsessie2stopt() {
  (function() {
    var start = new Date;
    start.setHours(23, 30, 0); // 11pm

    function pad(num) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
    }

    function tick() {
      var now = new Date;
      if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      }
      var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
      var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
      var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
      var ss = pad(remain % 60);
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hh + " hours and " + mm + " minutes and " + ss + " seconds to go!";
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
  })();
}
totsessie2stopt();
// End countdown
```

It is just a countdown timer.

The problem is that this function will not run when I put it inside setTimeout(function() { ... } here: https://jsfiddle.net/cx59L387/ This function should run on the given time of line 2.

```
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "This message will display at a given time on line 2!";



// Begin countdown
function totsessie2stopt() {
  (function() {
    var start = new Date;
    start.setHours(23, 30, 0); // 11pm

    function pad(num) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
    }

    function tick() {
      var now = new Date;
      if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      }
      var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
      var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
      var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
      var ss = pad(remain % 60);
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hh + " hours and " + mm + " minutes and " + ss + " seconds to go!";
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
  })();
}
totsessie2stopt();
// End countdown
```

}, totsessie1);

Inside setTimeout(function() { ... } other functions are working ok. I'm struggling already a couple of days to find out how I could run the countdown timer within it. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot!

Grid

Comment: The `totsessie1` variable has an enourmous value, so the timeout would execute after a long time

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios other functions inside setTimeout(function() { ... } are running ok, without delay, i don't know what you exactly mean

Comment: What they are saying is you have `setTimeout(function, totsessie1)`, where `totsessie1` is a variable. In the provided code that variable not defined, hens settimeout doesn't fire.

Comment: @vanown i believe it wll fire because line 7 will run, maybe we misunderstand each other? you have any advice how i will run line 37 just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Apart form the issue that `totsessie1` variable has a very high value, another reason for why your timeout function doesn´t run inside another timeout function is this part of code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
```

You are calling the `tick` function when to DOM is loaded, but you are forgetting that as it is inside a timeout function, the DOM would been already loaded when you attach the EventListener, so the function will never be called. Instead, just call the function normally:

```
tick();
```

Comment: @AlexanderPalacios this seems to fix it, using tick(); instead of document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);, has totsessie1 also a very high value on https://jsfiddle.net/szua2fed/ ?

Comment: In this script: https://jsfiddle.net/cx59L387/ - the first `setTimeout` function has a very high timeout value, so it would execute after a long time. That´s because your `totsessie1` you are using as timeout has a very high value when you do: `var totsessie1 = new Date(sessie1.getFullYear(), sessie1.getMonth(), sessie1.getDate(), 22, 35, 0, 0) - sessie1;`.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of complication here, possibly from adapting code. It looks like you just want to start the count down after a given amount of time, in the example below it will do this after 3000ms, you can change that.

For example I have removed the content loaded as I would guess by the time the timeout has run, that wont be an issue, The setTimeout delay has been moved into neater function that calls totsessie2stopt(), and the closure removed as not required.

```
// Begin countdown
function totsessie2stopt() {
 
    var start = new Date;
    start.setHours(23, 30, 0); // 11pm

    function pad(num) {
      return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
    }

    function tick() {
      var now = new Date;
      if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
        start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
      }
      var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
      var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
      var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
      var ss = pad(remain % 60);
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = " Still " + hh + " hours and " + mm + " minutes and " + ss + " seconds to go!";
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    }

    tick();

}

// call totsession2stopt after 3000 ms
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "This message will display at a given time on line 2!";
  totsessie2stopt();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: The goal is that both functions can be set to a specfic time. Once the message has been given it should set at that moment a countdown message until a time thats also already been given. I believe now it doesnt.